# jsf composite components getConvertedValue fired too early

Tags: jsf, children, composite-component

In my Application I have created a compositeComponent which contains a bunch of input fields (eg. street, city, country). The component extends the `UIInput`, because I want to return a full `Location` object created by the input fields. 
The Problem is that the `getConvertedValue()` of the compositeComponent is fired before the inputTexts get submitted, so the values are always null.

What do I do wrong?

**The composite component:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface componentType="locationInput">
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
</composite:interface>


<composite:implementation>
    <style>
.noPadding td {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
</style>
    <span id="#{cc.id}"> <p:panelGrid styleClass="noPadding" id="grd">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Straße/Nr." />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText value="#{cc.street}" size="30" required="true" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{cc.houseNr}" size="4" required="true" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:20px" />
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputLabel value="PLZ" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText value="#{cc.zipCode}" size="30" required="true" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Stadt" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText value="#{cc.city}" size="30" required="true" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:20px" />
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Land" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:autoComplete forceSelection="true" dropdown="true"
                        required="true" cache="true" value="#{cc.country}"
                        completeMethod="#{countryBean.complete}" var="entry"
                        scrollHeight="200" itemValue="#{entry}" itemLabel="#{entry.name}"
                        converter="countryConverter" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </span>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

---

**Its FacesComponent class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.NamingContainer;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@FacesComponent("locationInput")
public class LocationInput extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSubmittedValue() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object submittedValue) {
        System.out.println("THIS IS FIRED BEFORE THE COUNTRY/CITY/... gets submitted");
        return new Location(getStreet(), getCity(), getCountry());
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.getStateHelper().put("countryValue", country);
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return (String) this.getStateHelper().get("countryValue");
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.getStateHelper().put("cityValue", city);
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return (String) this.getStateHelper().get("cityValue");
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.getStateHelper().put("zipCodeValue", zipCode);
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return (String) this.getStateHelper().get("zipCodeValue");
    }

    public void setHouseNr(String houseNr) {
        this.getStateHelper().put("houseNrValue", houseNr);
    }

    public String getHouseNr() {
        return (String) this.getStateHelper().get("houseNrValue");
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.getStateHelper().put("streetValue", street);
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return (String) this.getStateHelper().get("streetValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this with the [processing] tag. Is this a question about the Processing language?

Comment: No, clearly not. I removed the tag. @OP: please carefully read tag descriptions before adding tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getStreet()`, `getCity()`and `getCountry()` will not be updated untill the *Update Model Values* Phase, So it's normal to get `null` values while your are in the *Process Validation* Phase.

An alternative solution is to use the `binding` attribute in your inputs, like:

```
 <p:inputText binding="#{cc.street}" size="30" required="true" />
```

And then use it like below in your backing bean:

```
private UIInput street;

@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
    ....
   String streetValue = (String) street.getSubmittedValue();
    ....
}
```

**See also:**

- [Composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html)
- [Composite Componen wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)
- [Composite Components in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: Thanks for this info, didn't knew about that since I'm quite new to jsf and especially to composite components.